# Do we stay airside at Delhi T3?

Tags: transit, india

We are flying LHR to DEL by BA arriving T3 and then flying DEL to Kathmandu by Indigo from T3. We have two separate tickets.

Can we stay airside at Delhi T3 or do we have to enter India and then go through check in/security again?

We have multiple entry Tourist Visas. If we have to enter India, how long will it normally take to make the transfer, as we have 3.5 hours between flights.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to re-check your baggage because your tickets were booked separately, you will have to enter India. This is something to check with Indigo, your airline.

Also 3.5 hours should be enough to make your connection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can stay at airside if you have a connecting flight, but do ask the airline service provider about the same. As in my case I got my baggage shifted without me even bothering about the luggage. So in that case you can continue your journey without entering India (Though you're missing out on the chance of looking at the world's biggest democratic country). Bon Voyage

Comment: Answers become lot more bearable and great when not written in a formal way, this is what i think, if you don't agree that's okay with me.